# Seeking a better login authentication solution in nodejs and koa

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

I created an app in nodejs and koa2

app.js

```
'use strict';
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();
const port = 3000;
const router = require('./router');
const path = require("path")
const views = require("koa-views");
const bodyParser = require("koa-bodyparser");
const koastatic = require("koa-static");
app.use(koastatic(path.join( __dirname,  "./static")))
app.use(views(path.join(__dirname, "./view"), {extension: "ejs"}))
router(app);
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

There are some router files in folder `router`, e.g.

index.js

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = (app) => {
  fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach(file => {
    if (file === 'index.js') { return; }
    const route = require(`./${file}`);
    app.use(route.routes()).use(route.allowedMethods());
  });
}
```

There are some pages that require login to access, e.g.

dashboard.js

```
'use strict';
const Router = require("koa-router");
const router = new Router({prefix: '/dashboard'});
router
    .get('/', async (ctx, next) => {
        let login = ctx.cookies.get('login') || "";
        if (!login) {
            ctx.redirect('/login');
        } else {
            let isexist = //check login status
            if (isexist && login) {
                await ctx.render("dashboard", {
                    current_service: "dashboard"
                });
            } else {
                ctx.redirect('/login');
            }
        }
    })
module.exports = router;
```

It works well, but there are lots of pages, if I use this way to determine these pages that require a login to access, it seems unreasonable, is there a better solution? Thank you.

Comment: I have never used KOA, and it looks like it is missing a few features that I would want in a router when it comes to NodeJS development. Most modern NodeJS applications use Express: https://expressjs.com/ it has type support, middleware, and a lot of Node packages for support. You will also find plenty of MERN stack examples.

Comment: I was going to suggest a middleware like in Express `.get('/', authenticate, async (req,res) =>`  but I don't know Koa and if it supports middlewares

Comment: @JustinRice it looks like [Koa](https://koajs.com/) is newer than Express and was made by the same team...

Comment: @JustinRice Koa is from the makers of express. The big difference is that it uses `async/await` instead of callbacks. Most features are available but need to be installed separately, this way you have a smaller (and faster) server since most users don't need everything that express comes with

Comment: I had never heard of Koa before, but suddenly I'm very interested. Indeed, callback functions feel old in Express, in comparison to `async/await`. Time for replacement.

Comment: @Reyno I am now quite intrigued as well. The question asks for a better solution to an authentication problem. I would think for the amount of middleware needed for SECURE login, one might just want to use some of the already established modules for express rather than coding your own.  I suppose the size and distribution of the app here matters. I do like KOA's bare-bones approach. I have been in the Flask space for a bit and really like the bare-bones model. I will check out KOA.

Comment: @JustinRice Yes but luckly Koa has a [wiki page](https://github.com/koajs/koa/wiki) containing TONS of existing middlewares and frameworks. Some are from the community others are made by themselves. So definitely check it out if you're looking into Koa

Comment: As for OP I'd suggest looking at [middlewares](https://github.com/koajs/koa#middleware), this way you can make a generic function that checks the users cookies.